# PHP date() wrong_timestamp

Tags: php, time

I'm doing a cms article page, the problem is the posts timestamp always are 01 march 1970, What am I doing wrong? Thanks

UPDATED

```
<span id="date">Posted  
<?php 

 setlocale( LC_ALL, NULL);
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

 $timeStamp = $article['article_timestamp'];
 $uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
 echo strftime('%A, %d de '.$uppercaseMonth.' de %Y', strtotime($timeStamp));

?>
</span>
```

Comment: `strtotime('today')` what did you expect...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the datetime or timestamp mapped with that article then only it will display the correct date.
 So replace strtotime('today') with the strtotime($article_date)

```
<span id="date">Posted  
                <?php //delete next two lines to have the default time (in english)
                    setlocale( LC_ALL, NULL);
                    //setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL); --------------  English
                    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    $uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
                    echo strftime( '%A, %d de ' .$uppercaseMonth. ' de %Y', strtotime($article_date));
                ?></span>
```

Comment: Can you give it a look? i updated my anwser. sry for the trouble but I really can't see what's wrong